# Wget links ending in ".tex" from a website

Tags: bash, awk, wget

I have around 20000 html files and they all contain links to .tex files (but they also contain other information).

I'd like a script that can wget all the .tex files, preferably using awk. The html files contain portions that look like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/f/1q1m-20140227.tex"  ><img src="/images/save.png" save></a>
```

and obviously also contain links to other things.

I'm sorry if it sounds like I haven't researched the question, I just don't know anything about regex or awk.
This is what I have so far but it gives no results:

```
for i in {0..20}
do
    awk '/\bhttp[\w%+\/-]+?tex\b/' $i.htm >> final-test
done
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me! :-)

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. Try this yourself and come back with specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: looks like a homework, no try on it, and wait for answer only.

Comment: @LeonardBlunderbuss
I'm sorry, I realize how my question sounds. I just have no idea how to use regex and I have no experience using awk at all. I'd love some help from somebody who actually knows what they're talking about.
I don't need you to write me the script, I'd just like some help with finding the links ending in .tex

Comment: using regex to parse HTML is a bad idea. Try a web scraping framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I ended up not using awk at all. This is what I did:

```
for i in {1..20000}
do
    lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers $i.htm >> all-links
done

cat all-links | grep .tex >> texlinks
wget -c -i texlinks

exit;
```

It's not perfect and definitely not very efficient but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Regex? Why?

```
wget -i foo.htm -r -A .tex
```

Comment: Sadly, this also downloads other things (although it deletes them afterwards), so it's not very efficient.